# stop line before end node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider a line

`\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1, 0);`

Is it somehow possible to make the line stop at e.g. 70% of the way from the start coordinate `(0,0)` to the end coordinate `(1,0)`, i.e. so that the arrow head is at `(0.7,0)`?

Of course without explicitly calculate that point manually. I'd like to define the two endpoints, but then draw the line and sto before we actually get to that end point.

EDIT: I hope this ASCII art makes it a little bit clearer:

```
(0,0)         (.7,0)     (1,0)
  --------------->
```

Comment: Asymptote (MetaPost internal) can do it easily!

Comment: @flawr -- a handrawn sketch would be helpful

Comment: What is the point of this? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: @AndréC I want to draw a line segment: The line this segment lives on is defined by two points. But the endpoints of the segment do not coincide with these two points.

Comment: @flawr I understand what you want to do, but I have no idea what it could be useful for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of possible solution is use of `decorations.markings` TikZ library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={markings,% switch on markings
            mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}}
]
\draw [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

From OP comment follows quite unusual demand (not clear from question). It seems, that (s)he looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={markings,% switch on markings
            mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}}
]
\draw [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [-Straight Barb] (0,-2mm) -- (0.7*1,-2mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

what is the same if you draw the second line as

```
\draw [-Straight Barb] (0,-2mm) -- (0.7,-2mm);
```

or

```
\draw [-Straight Barb, shorten >=3mm] (0,-2mm) -- (1,-2mm);
```

Frankly said, I do not understand your intention.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I think I was a little bit unclear: Is it also possible to end the line itself early?

Comment: @flawr, hat doesn't follow from your question. Why you not simple draw shorter line? See addendum to my answer.

Comment: This is what I mean by saying to "stop the line at 70%" - the reason is that the line segment I want to draw is on a line that is defined by two points, but the end points of the segments do not coincide with the points that define the line.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! The `shorten` keyword was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete Zarko's answer, it's possible to use `calc` library to stop the line at a certain percentage of its lenght. `shorten` option allows to do it when we exactly know the distance to be shortened, but when this distance is unknown or want a percentatge, `calc` is better.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                    positioning,
                calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill] (A) {};
\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill, right=2cm of A] (B) {};

\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill] at (0,5mm) {};
\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill] at (4,15mm) {};

\draw [-Straight Barb] (A) -- node[above, sloped] {70\%} ($(A)!.7!(B)$);
\draw [-Straight Barb] (0,5mm) -- node[above, sloped] {95\%}  ($(0,5mm)!.95!(4,15mm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is also a very elegant solution!